# C++ stuck in infinite loop of equal operator assignment

Tags: c++

I've found myself in a sort of hellish nightmare where I am trying to use the equals operator to re-assign an object that references itself through another internal object.

The goal of this design was to

1. Create an object called `Foo`
2. Create an internal object called `FooEventHandler` that contains a reference to `Foo`
3. Pass `FooEventHandler` around to an `EventEmitter` so that it can call `Foo` functions on events

I've provided the tiniest amount of code to illustrate the goal and the problem at the same time. I've had no issues with my `Event` module to date, including my paradigm of having extended `EventHandler`s reference their parent objects (in this case `Foo`) and be sent to an `EventEmitter` so that it can call any `Foo` function, sort of like an implementation of a lambda function.

However, after about a year of using this design, I hit a major road block when I needed to do something like `foo1 = foo2` (= operator) or `Foo foo1 = foo2` (copy constructor). I ran into the issue with references not being assignable (`FooEventHandler`'s reference to `Foo`). So I am trying to fix that by writing manual copy ctor and `=` operator, and now I am stuck in an infinite loop for the `=` operator.

As I dig through this, *I don't even know what I want to accomplish* let alone how to fix it. One purpose of the `=` operator would be when I want to update a `Foo` object by simply replacing it with a new `Foo` object, eg `foo1 = foo2`. But, I am spinning my wheels trying to figure out what I want to do with `Foo`'s `EventHandler`. `foo1`'s `EventHandler` should still reference itself, so maybe in the `=` operator I don't re-assign the `EventHandler`.. but, maybe I do because `foo1` should be `=` to `foo2` whose `EventHandler` references `foo2`!.. or maybe not.. or maybe yes??!

I am hoping someone can look at this problem and give me some clarity on what I should do.

Notes: I am in c++ 98

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// EventHandler and EventEmitter are just included to display my intent 
class EventHandler {
    public:
        virtual ~EventHandler(){}  
        virtual void HandleEvent(/*some event*/) = 0;
};

class EventEmitter {
    public:
        std::vector<EventHandler*> handlers;
        void AddHandler(EventHandler *handler){
            this->handlers.push_back(handler);
        }
        void EmitEvent(/*some event*/){
            for(size_t i = 0; i < this->handlers.size(); i++){
                this->handlers.at(i)->HandleEvent(/*some event*/);
            }
        }
};

// The problem arises in Foo/FooEventHandler with circular references
class Foo {
    public:
        
        // This object is designed to carry Foo to the EventEmitter
        class FooEventHandler : public EventHandler {
            public:
                Foo &foo;
                FooEventHandler(Foo &foo)
                    :EventHandler(),
                     foo(foo)
                {
                    printf("FooEventHandler CONSTRUCTOR\n");   
                }
                FooEventHandler(const FooEventHandler &event_handler)
                    :EventHandler(),
                     foo(event_handler.foo)
                {
                    printf("FooEventHandler COPY\n");   
                }
                FooEventHandler operator=(const FooEventHandler& event_handler) {
                    printf("FooEventHandler =\n");   
                    this->foo = event_handler.foo;
                }
                ~FooEventHandler(){
                    printf("FooEventHandler DESTRUCTOR\n");   
                }
                void HandleEvent(/*some event*/){
                    this->foo.HandleSomeEvent();
                }
                
        };
    
        // Foo is just some generic object with a custom handler to ref itself 
        FooEventHandler event_handler;
        Foo(std::string name)
            :event_handler(*this)
        {
            printf("Foo CONSTRUCTOR\n");   
        }
        Foo(const Foo &foo)
            :event_handler(foo.event_handler)
        {
            printf("Foo COPY\n"); 
        }
        Foo operator=(const Foo& foo)
        {
            printf("Foo =\n");    
            this->event_handler = foo.event_handler;
        }
        ~Foo(){
            printf("Foo DESTRUCTOR\n");   
        }
        void HandleSomeEvent(/*some event*/){
            printf("Look at me handling an event");
        }
};

int main()
{
    printf("Foo1 create\n");
    Foo foo1("a");

    printf("Foo2 equal\n");
    Foo foo2("b");
    // start infinite loop of ='s
    foo2 = foo1;
}
```

Comment: Step thought a loop with a debugger and you'll usually see why it's looping.

Comment: `Foo operator=(const Foo& foo)` promises to return a `Foo`, but doesn't. This will cause problems. Same with `FooEventHandler operator=(const FooEventHandler& event_handler)`

Comment: You have nasty UB with this `Foo &foo;`. Note that this reference is initialized with itself when constructor `Foo(std::string name)`is used.

Comment: You have [_a lot_ of errors and warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/cTEa16) that you should take care of.

Comment: Side note: reference members are usually more trouble than they're worth. You can't re-assign a reference, so no matter what you do, the assignment operator is always going to be weird. In this case you only have an event handler and there is no point to trying to point it at a different `Foo` so you could make an assignment operator for `FooEventHandler` that does absolutely nothing and remove the assignment operator (and copy constructor) from `Foo`, but this probably doesn't do what you need it to do for the non-simplified version.

Comment: Have you tried the tip in the first comment ? In your code fragment, I see TWO implementations for the = assignment operator. It looks like Foo and FooEventHandler *both* implement the = operator,, and they use eachother *mutually*. So you get an endless loop, where they keep calling eachother.

Comment: Handy reading: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Because the nasty is in `FooEventHandler`, it needs to handle Three or Five, and once it does, `Foo` is in the clear and can observe the Rule of Zero. The compiler will do its job and produce a correct special member function that calls `FooEventHandler`'s custom function.

Comment: Can you move to C++17?

Comment: @MarekR I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Eljay Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Goodies Yes I understand. I think I just have to redesign everything.

Answer (score 0):

[X-Y answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Make the whole problem go away by killing the source of the problem: the separate event handler class.

In comes  [`boost::function`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/function.html) to supply a generic function interface for event callback (almost) directly to `Foo` and [`boost::bind`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) to abstract away the `Foo`-ness.

Note that this uses Boost, and Boost can be a pain to install. If your OS or Development environment's package manager has it ready to go, might as well use it. If not, take comfort in `function` and `bind` being header-only libraries and much easier to get working than the libraries that need compiling.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

template<class T> // now a template to allow for different types of events
class EventEmitter
{
public:
    typedef boost::function<void(T&)> handler;
    std::vector<handler> handlers;
    void AddHandler(handler handle)
    {
        handlers.push_back(handle);
    }
    void EmitEvent(T& evt)
    {
        // No range-for. Oh well. Still no need for at. The loop bounds make 
        // overrun impossible
        for (size_t i = 0; i < handlers.size(); i++)
        {
            handlers[i](evt); // call the function
        }
    }
};

class Foo
{
private:
    // we can hide the event handlers away from prying eyes.
    void HandleEvent(std::string &)
    {
        printf("Look at me handling a string event\n");
    }

public:
    // Foo might as well register itself on construction, so passing in the emitter
    Foo(EventEmitter<std::string> & emitter,
        std::string /*name*/)
    {
        // Bind this and the handler function together
        emitter.AddHandler(boost::bind(&Foo::HandleEvent, this, _1));
        printf("Foo CONSTRUCTOR\n");
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        printf("Foo DESTRUCTOR\n");
    }
    // but if we want to install event handlers later, here's a public function
    void HandleEvent2(std::string &)
    {
        printf("Look at me handling a different string event\nOK. It's the same event, but it proves the point.\n");
    }

};

int main()
{
    printf("Foo1 create\n");
    EventEmitter<std::string> test;
    Foo foo(test, "a");
    // same as above, but this time with foo in place of this
    test.AddHandler(boost::bind(&Foo::HandleEvent2, &foo, _1));
    std::string event;
    test.EmitEvent(event);
}
```

Failed attempts:

`Foo` contains an `EventHandler` that needs to know the owning `Foo` in order to call it. But what if `Foo` IS the `EventHandler`? `Foo` implementing `EventHandler` eliminates the circular nature of the problem because no one knows `Foo` quite like `Foo` does.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// EventHandler and EventEmitter are just included to display my intent
class EventHandler {
    public:
        virtual ~EventHandler(){}
        virtual void HandleEvent(/*some event*/) = 0;
};

class EventEmitter {
    public:
        std::vector<EventHandler*> handlers;
        void AddHandler(EventHandler *handler){
            this->handlers.push_back(handler);
        }
        void EmitEvent(/*some event*/){
            for(size_t i = 0; i < this->handlers.size(); i++){
                this->handlers.at(i)->HandleEvent(/*some event*/);
            }
        }
};

// Foo IS the FooEventHandler 
class Foo: public EventHandler {
    public:

        void HandleEvent(/*some event*/){
            // doesn't need to know Foo. It IS Foo
            printf("Look at me handling an event\n");
        }

        Foo(std::string /*name*/)
        {
            printf("Foo CONSTRUCTOR\n");
        }
        ~Foo(){
            printf("Foo DESTRUCTOR\n");
        }
};

int main()
{
    printf("Foo1 create\n");
    Foo foo1("a");

    // start infinite loop of ='s
    EventEmitter test;
    test.AddHandler(&foo1);
    test.EmitEvent();
}
```

The whole problem just goes away and leaves you with much simpler code. Kept this because it is really simple.

But it will not meet the Asker's needs. I wrote this before re-reading the question and the C++98 requirement. It uses [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for event callback and [Lambda Expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to replace `boost::bind`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template<class T> // now a template to allow for different types of events
class EventEmitter
{
public:
    using handler = std::function<void(T&)>; // simplify naming
    std::vector<handler> handlers;
    void AddHandler(handler handle)
    {
        handlers.push_back(handle);
    }
    void EmitEvent(T& evt)
    {
        // range-based for loop. Can't go out of bounds
        for (const auto & handle : handlers)
        {
            handle(evt); // call the function
        }
    }
};

class Foo
{
private:
    // we can hide the event handlers away from prying eyes.
    void HandleEvent(std::string &)
    {
        printf("Look at me handling a string event\n");
    }

public:
    // Foo might as well register itself on construction, so passing in the emitter
    Foo(EventEmitter<std::string> & emitter,
        std::string /*name*/)
    {
        // install lambda expression as handler function
        // lambda captures this so it knows which Foo to call
        emitter.AddHandler([this](std::string& evt)
        {
            HandleEvent(evt); //call wrapped function
            return;
        });
        printf("Foo CONSTRUCTOR\n");
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        printf("Foo DESTRUCTOR\n");
    }
    // but if we want to install event handlers later, here's a public function
    void HandleEvent2(std::string &)
    {
        printf("Look at me handling a different string event\nOK. It's the same event, but it proves the point.\n");
    }

};

int main()
{
    printf("Foo1 create\n");
    EventEmitter<std::string> test;
    Foo foo(test, "a");
    // install outside of foo
    // lambda captures foo by reference. We don't want to operator on a copy
    test.AddHandler([&foo](std::string& evt)
                {
                    foo.HandleEvent2(evt); // wrap public handler function
                    return;
                });

    std::string event;
    test.EmitEvent(event);
}
```

Not quite as simple, but handling multiple types of events is doomed to be more complicated. Kept because the Asker's not the only person out there.

Comment: Unfortunately my event handlers are templates, ie `EventHandler<T>`.Someone like `Foo` will want to handle more than one event. This would work if every `Event` was of a different type, that way there could be many `HandleEvent` functions with different signatures and my `Emtiter` can figure out which one to use. But as soon as there's two `Event`s that are of type `std::string` for example, and `Foo` cares about both, I'd be hosed. I do agree that redesign is necessary, though.

Comment: @ony_pox232 I don't have boost available to test out a boost version of this. That said if you're stuck on c++98, you probably won't have Boost either.

Comment: @user4581301 https://wandbox.org/ is an online compiler that has boost built in

Comment: There is probably an elegant way to do this that I'm not thinking of, but at this point I'd fall back on C. The event function gets an additional `void*` parameter and installs `static` member functions. The `static` member function casts the `void*` to the correct type and then uses it to call the correct function.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah to be honest, I'm always leery about telling people to pull in Boost if they aren't already using it. It's a big hammer and takes a bit of head-scratching to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the infinite loop. These functions call each other.

```
Foo(const Foo &foo)        :event_handler(foo.event_handler)
    {
        printf("Foo COPY\n"); 
    }

FooEventHandler(const FooEventHandler &event_handler)
                :EventHandler(),
                 foo(event_handler.foo)
            {
                printf("FooEventHandler COPY\n");   
            }
```

I think FooEventHandler should not has a reference to Foo from aspect of abstraction. You should change your desing.